# Does Skype have a keyboard shortcut for switching among conversations?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, skype

Does Skype have a keyboard shortcut for switching among conversations?

I've searched the web and through Skype forums, and can't find anything. There's something under the Tools → Accessibility menu that is called "Extended Keyboard Navigation" – but what that does seems to be a mystery as well.

Answer (score 13):

**For Mac OS X users:**

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> switches between tabs in the main window.

Comment: You'd think they'd make this consistent between platforms, but on MSFT's own platform this shortcut doesn't exist. *sigh*

Answer (score 13):

I'd like to add just one thing to the others.

With ALT+1 and ALT+2 you can select the list of contacts/conversations, then use up/down to select a contact, and either space to see the conversation, or enter to get into the conversation (meaning that the focus will go into the edit box).

However, this is still not as simple as using Ctrl+TAB for example... :(

Answer (score 8):

Using the tips by **totesz** I made a script for [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

If you are in windows, I recommend that you get Autohotkey. Then you can use this simple
script:

```
#SingleInstance force
#IfWinActive ahk_class tSkMainForm
;
;   This Skype shortcuts will make pressing Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down work
;   to switch between conversation windows.
;   
;   To do that normally we need to focus the Recent panel with Alt+2
;   (Alt+1 will focus the contacts panel)
;   Next we press up or down to switch between conversations
;   Then press enter to move the focus to the input box on the selected
;   conversation
;
;
;   *Note: this only works with the conversations in the "Recent" panel

ConversationUp()
{
    Send, {AltDown}2{AltUp}
    Sleep, 100
    Send, {Up}{Enter}
    return
}

ConversationDown()
{
    Send, {AltDown}2{AltUp}
    Sleep, 100
    Send, {Down}{Enter}
    return
}


;Ctrl+Down move one conversation down
^Down::ConversationDown()

;Ctrl+Up move one conversation up
^Up::ConversationUp()

;Ctrl+Tab move one conversation down
^Tab::ConversationDown()

;Ctrl+Shift+Tab move one conversation up
^+Tab::ConversationUp()
```

Save the script as `skype.ahk`, if you have Autohotkey installed, double click
the file to run the script. Then you will be able to use the following shortcuts in the Skype window:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to move to the next conversation.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to move to the previous conversation.

Comment: +1, this is a dirty hack, but it works, and I love it :)

Comment: It seems like `Alt+2` is now not working in skype... Do you know, what's the reason?

Comment: I have not used Skype for Windows in a while, maybe they changed something in a recent update? What version of Skype are you using?

Comment: Just updated my Windows Skype, the script still works. Did you change something in the script? or Have some other Autohotkey scripts running?

Comment: Script is totally fine, I just manually press `Alt+2` and the tab with recent conversation doesn't get selected. However, _sometimes_, it does work. And `Alt+1` always works. I have no clue. I'm using the latest Skype under Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Hey, I just noticed `Alt+2` began to work after I closed Photoshop. However, it still was working after I reopened Photoshop. Still not sure what does this mean.

Comment: This script is awesome, but why does single Up (edit last message) stop working? I can't see that any of the commands in the script would interfere with that.

Answer (score 5):

## No.

And indeed there's [a feature request](https://jira.skype.com/browse/SCW-2569) for it on Skype's site.

Comment: Is the link dead?

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:**
`Alt-Tab` and rotate through all the windows (including other apps) until you reach the conversation window you want.

**Method 2:**
If the focused window is not Skype, use a shortcut key (refer to screenshot below) to bring the main Skype window into focus.
Press `Alt-2` to get the conversations tab up, then use up-down arrow keys to navigate to the conversation you want.

[image: Hotkey Options]

Answer (score 1):

I do not use Skype very much but if the conversations are in separate tabs like some IM clients (e.g. Pidgin) then you can perhaps try to use CTRL + TAB (+ SHIFT for reverse) to switch between them.

This also works in most browsers with tabs.

Comment: But not in Skype. :)

Comment: OK, been trying a bit now.

If you go to the conversations tab and use the up and down arrow keys then you can actually navigate pretty easy within the conversations. Simply press Space when you need to select one.

In case you just need swapping between two then it is simply: down + space. To go back: up + space.

Comment: One problem with above is that focus on the writing box is lost...

Comment: That and you have to use the mouse to click conversations, and then you can't use the keyboard to switch once you're in conversation again. THAT and it's more than one keypress to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Change view to Compact mode (View -> Compact view) so you can use ALT+TAB to switch between open conversations.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Tools/Options/IM disable the "Enable Tabbed Conversations" checkbox and then you can Alt Tab between them.

Comment: Odd, I don't see that option, and I'm using the latest Skype on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, `Ctrl` + `Tab` works for me.

Of course your focus has to be on the Skype tabbed conversation window, and it should work. (I'm using skype for business by the way, don't know if this works on Vanilla Skype)