# Skype keeps making me automatically invisible

Tags: mac, skype, automation

I keep getting made invisible automatically by skype.  It doesn't even appear to happen at consistent intervals.  Sometimes it doesn't happen at all, sometimes it happens every 5 seconds.  I don't want this to happen, but I can't find an option to disable it.  Does anybody know if it's possible to disable the invisible status or prevent the timer at all?  Or is there a hotkey that I am inadvertently pressing that activates invisible mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This could happen when you're logged into your account using multiple devices, so the statuses could be not in sync.

For workaround there are some [cloud-based chat commands](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10042/what-cloud-based-chat-commands-and-roles-are-available-in-skype) which allows you to see where you're logged in and you can logout from the remote sessions.

1. Create an empty conversation.
2. Type command in the message textbox:

   ```
   /showplaces
   ```

   > Lists other endpoints that can receive push notifications for calls and IMs for this Skype account.
3. If you want to logout from remote online endpoints, then execute:

   ```
   /remotelogout
   ```

   > Sign out all other instances except the current one. This will also stop push notifications on all other instances.

Answer (score 0):

To answer if there is a [Skype hotkey](https://superuser.com/questions/58274/does-skype-have-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-among-conversations) or not, the answer is maybe - it can be customized so it depends on your copy of Skype.

It is possible you've received a malicious script which does this as well (see the same link as above which shows how to write a custom script) - although I think unlikely.

Comment: I'm using the mac version and there's no tools menu.  I looked for a keyboard shortcuts section but couldn't find anything.  I'm wondering if I perhaps missed something.

Comment: Windows machinery has Tools.  Macs have Preferences.